# workbench.js is removed in Visual studio code version 1.70.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I notice that since version 1.70.0, VSCode has removed `%localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-browser\workbench` folder.

Hence it broke extensions that rely on the file `workbench.js` in this folder.

Is there any workaround for this problem or the extensions need to be re-written?

Comment: what do these extensions do with this file

Comment: mostly custom ui extensions

Comment: an you name an example extension, are extensions able to modify these files

Comment: example: https://github.com/iCharlesZ/vscode-live2d

Comment: if these extensions modify files that are not part of the public API, they have to modified and be aware that there are multiple versions of set the engine version in `package,json`, it looks like live2d v1.8.1 is compatible with VSC 1.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these files have moved to

```
resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-sandbox\workbench
```